# VS Code: Code gets pushed to the right when I save

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When I save my file, a block of code gets messed up and end up being indented to the right.

Here is a screenshot to demonstrate the problem: [image]

The code works but it's just not visually pleasant.

I have tried to uninstall some extensions, but none of them had to do with HTML.

Comment: What happens when you "unindent" it?

Comment: @GalAbra Even if I intend the block of code and make it look how it should, the moment I hit save it goes back to the state mentioned on the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing the extra " from line 645 to 647 that was causing the right indention.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio Code, you can use the hotkeys to reformat your code. The following hotkeys is for formatting your document, it works for html and other kinds of files as well, such as javascript files, json files, etc.

[Format Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNeV4.png)

Note: Different computer may have different settings. To search for hotkeys, ctrl + shift + P.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try "save as" and give the file a new name. It might just save the changes the way you want it to.